# How to Change a Picture inside of a Table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

When I press the plus button, I would like to change the picture into minus

[image]

When you have toggled out, you can see the minus picture and you click on the picture, it will be changed into plus picture.

***Questions:***
I do not know how to create it based on description above by using jQuery.

Thanks!

```js
$(function () {
    $('tr.parent td')
        .on("click", "span.btnn", function () {
        var idOfParent = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        $('tr.child-' + idOfParent).toggle('slow');
    });
});

$('tr.child').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>  
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="parent" id=1048>
        <td><span class="btnn">2015 July </span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span class="btnn"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_plus-16.png" /></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child child-1048">
        <td>July 7</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child child-1048">
        <td>July 7</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="parent" id=5000>
        <td><span class="btnn">2015 July </span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span class="btnn"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_plus-16.png" /></span></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="child child-5000">
        <td>July 7</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child child-5000">
        <td>July 7</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this get image using this.children[0].src  from jquery

```js
$(function () {
        $('tr.parent td')
            .on("click", "span.btnn", function () {
                var idOfParent = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
                $('tr.child-' + idOfParent).toggle('slow');
          if( this.children[0].src=="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_plus-16.png")
      this.children[0].src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/player-set/154/loop-minus-16.png";
          else
             this.children[0].src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_plus-16.png"
            });
    });


    $('tr.child').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            a
        </th>
        <th>
            b
        </th>
        <th>
            c
        </th>
        <th>
            d
        </th>  
        <th></th>
    </tr>
 
 
 <tr class="parent" id=1048>
  <td><span class="btnn">2015 July </span></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><span class="btnn"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_plus-16.png" /></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="child child-1048">
  <td>July 7</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td><test/td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="child child-1048">
  <td>July 7</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>


 <tr class="parent" id=5000>
  <td><span class="btnn">2015 July </span></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><span class="btnn"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_plus-16.png" /></span></td>
 </tr>   
 <tr class="child child-5000">
  <td>July 7</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="child child-5000">
  <td>July 7</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$(function () {
    $('tr.parent td')
        .on("click", "span.btnn", function () {
            var self = $(this),
                parent = self.parents('tr'),
                idOfParent = parent.attr('id');
            $('tr.child-' + idOfParent).toggle('slow');
            parent.toggleClass('minus');
        });
    $('tr.child').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        a
    </th>
    <th>
        b
    </th>
    <th>
        c
    </th>
    <th>
        d
    </th>       
    <th></th>
</tr>


<tr class="parent" id=1048>
    <td><span class="btnn">2015 July </span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="btnn btnn-icon"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="child child-1048">
    <td>July 7</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="child child-1048">
    <td>July 7</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>


<tr class="parent" id=5000>
    <td><span class="btnn">2015 July </span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="btnn btnn-icon"></span></td>
</tr>           
<tr class="child child-5000">
    <td>July 7</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="child child-5000">
    <td>July 7</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.btnn-icon{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
    background:url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-   round/700/07_plus-16.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.minus .btnn-icon{
    background:url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/player-set/154/loop-minus-16.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vmyxa51o/

Answer (score 2):

You Can Change by Jquery Like this

```
<tr class="parent" id=5000>
    <td><span class="btnn">2015 July </span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="btnn" data-id="plus"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_plus-16.png" /></span></td>
</tr>
```

Just Add Data-id As Attribute in Span.btnn

Now Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
    {
      $('.btnn').click(function ()
      {
        var state = $(this).attr('data-id');
        if(state == 'plus')
        {
           //Change To Minus Image
          $(this).html('<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_minus-16.png">');
          $(this).attr('data-id','minus');
        }
        else
        {
           //Change To Plus Image
           $(this).html('<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/07_plus-16.png">');
          $(this).attr('data-id','plus');
        }
      })

    });
```